# Calling a function or subroutine

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm quite new to fortran, i'm trying to execute a function/subroutine but i'm getting an error `Explicit interface required`

This is my code:

```
function printmat(m)
    integer, dimension(:,:) :: m
    integer :: row,col
    row = size(m,1)
    col = size(m,2)
       do k=1,row
            print *, m(k,1:col)
       enddo
end function printmat

program test
    integer, dimension(5, 5) :: mat
    integer :: i,j
    do i=1,5
    do j=1,5
           mat(j,i) = real(i)/real(j)
    enddo
    enddo
    call printmat(mat)
end program test
```

But when i execute it i get:

```
Error: Explicit interface required for 'printmat' at (1): assumed-shape argument
```

Any idea of what could it be? I tried wrapping it into a module, but when i use "use modulename" in the program it gives me an error (tries to read it from a file with the same name)

Comment: If you have a problem with an error after "wrapping it into a module", please show that attempt, and how you compile it.  As this question stands, you seem to know that you can solve the requirement for an explicit interface with a module so it's unclear (to me) what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it into a module and make it a `subroutine` if you want to use it with `CALL`.

```
module printmat_module
contains
  subroutine printmat(m)
    integer, dimension(:,:) :: m
    integer :: row,col
    row = size(m,1)
    col = size(m,2)
    do k=1,row
       print *, m(k,1:col)
    enddo
  end subroutine printmat
end module printmat_module

program test
  use printmat_module
  integer, dimension(5, 5) :: mat
  integer :: i,j
  do i=1,5
     do j=1,5
        mat(j,i) = real(i)/real(j)
     enddo
  enddo
  call printmat(mat)
end program test
```

Alternatively you can just do what the compiler tells you and add an explicit interface to the `program`.

```
subroutine printmat(m)
  integer, dimension(:,:) :: m
  integer :: row,col
  row = size(m,1)
  col = size(m,2)
  do k=1,row
     print *, m(k,1:col)
  enddo
end subroutine printmat

program test
  interface
     subroutine printmat(m)
       integer, dimension(:,:) :: m
     end subroutine printmat
  end interface
  integer, dimension(5, 5) :: mat
  integer :: i,j
  do i=1,5
     do j=1,5
        mat(j,i) = real(i)/real(j)
     enddo
  enddo
  call printmat(mat)
end program test
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't read the last part of my post, i already tried that, and it says ´Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'printmat_module.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory´. I'm using gfortran, maybe it has something do do with that, i don't know.

Comment: @Ghost If I save the above code as `test.f90` and compile with `gfortran test.f90` it works just fine.

Comment: @Ghost I've added a second part without `module`.

Comment: @Ghost can you edit your question to tell us exactly what commands you are using to compile your program with modules, and what files the source code is stored in

Comment: Great - but please be aware you should be using the first solution, try to avoid writing explicit interfaces wherever and whenever you can. And you do understand why you need an interface in this case?